# Replace a word in a string using nested dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace a word in a string using nested dictionary if it contains key and value1 then replace the word with value2 of dictionary.

I have created dictionary like below.

```
RenameEnums = { 'DPST': {'Name': 'ENHANCEMENT', 'Rename': 
                      'D_ENHANCEMENT'},
                'BASE': {'Name': 'Cursor', 'Rename': 'CBase'}}

def replace(string,dict):
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
    line = line.replace(key, val)
    return line
```

I don't know how to access the second value of nested dictionary.
Expected Output:

**Case: 1** It should replace as it contains key as well ad value1

```
String: DPST ENHANCEMENT is not easy
Replaced: D_ENHANCEMENT is not east
```

**Case: 2** It should not replace as key is not present in string.

```
String: DSL is very easy in respect with ENHANCEMENT
```

Comment: `print( val['Name'], val['Rename'] )`

Comment: it looks like you replace `'DPST ENHANCEMENT'` with `'D_ENHANCEMENT'` but what if you have text `'DPST hello ENHANCEMENT'` ? Maybe better define it as list `[{'Name': 'DPST ENHANCEMENT', 'Rename': 
                      'D_ENHANCEMENT'}, ...]`

Comment: @PRUTHVIBEN, do you want to replace only value1 or the key as well? E.g. in Case 1, should the replaced string be `DPST D_ENHANCEMENT is not easy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to access the second value of nested dictionary.

In your code example, you can access the nested value as `val['Name']`.

In your for loop `for key, val in dictionary.items()`, val is actually another dictionary which can not be directly used in `string.replace()` function.

Try this:

```
RenameEnums = { 'DPST': {'Name': 'ENHANCEMENT', 'Rename': 
                  'D_ENHANCEMENT'},
            'BASE': {'Name': 'Cursor', 'Rename': 'CBase'}}

def replace(string, dict):
  for key, val in dict.items():
    # Check if key is present in the string
    if string.find(key) > -1:
      # Replace all occurrences of 'Name' with 'Rename'
      string = string.replace(val['Name'], val['Rename'])
  return string

line1 = "DPST ENHANCEMENT is not easy"
line1 = replace(line1, RenameEnums)
```